# Text Runaround in Sketch App

Tags: sketchapp

After searching around the web, I believe I've come to the conclusion that Sketch still does not have a text runaround feature. The clip-path property is available to us (https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/#applying-a-custom-shape) and will hopefully become available in all browsers (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). Does anyone have recommendations on how to create text runaround in Sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't right now...

https://twitter.com/sketchapp/status/461876580407844865?lang=fr

You can play with the feature "text on path" but you will never have something that look like what our browser can do.